# Is it possible to put a rectangle as background in the \author section?

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, presentations, block

In the `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}` Is it possible to put a rectangle as background in the \author section ?

A kind of block, so that the `\author` name has a background with light color.

Is it possible, if yes how?

I tried the `\begin{block}{a} ... \end{block}` and it compiles 'correct' but it makes the `\author` disappear.

Any kind of help is very appreciated

Comment: Actually I've just notice it does not disappear, it just put it at the top of the slide and it's just the name `a`

Comment: Please read [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author is already in a box, you just don't see it because the default colour is white. You can change the colour like the following:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\author{names}
\setbeamercolor{author}{bg=red}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you samcarter! Just one question, how to nivelate the level of red color? It's very intense and does not let distinguish the author text

Comment: @user178403 Either mix it with white (`red!50!white`) or use another colour you like, I just used it as an example.

Comment: got it, is there a way to remove the gray shadow that has at the bottom of the block?

Comment: @user178403 Per default there is no gray shadow. You will have to make a MWE that allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I've fixed, it has to do with all the packages I have. This one `\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}` I put % and gave the pure rectangle, thanks again.